# Special keys typed using Alt key in gVim

Tags: vim, special-characters

I found out that I can type some special characters using Alt key in gVim. Is there a documentation for these keys? How are they defined? Are they hard coded? `map` command do not show these mappings.
These are the keys I get with my keyboard. The blank space corresponds to keys that does some operation instead of type a special character.

```
à±²³´µ¶·¸¹°
ñ÷åòôùõéïðÛÝ
áó  çèêëì»§
úøãö îí¬®¯
```

These map to:

```
1234567890
qwertyuiop[]
as  ghjkl;'
zxcv nm,./
```

I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that everywhere when you use an international keyboard layout. There's nothing strange or even particularly vim-related to it.

Those glyphs are part of the [latin1 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and you can type more of them if you press the `Shift` key.

Comment: apparently gVim is the only editor that can type special characters with <kbd>alt</kbd> in Windows. Other editors just maps alt keys to menu. Well, now I know exactly why! Haha, thanks for not down-voting me.

Comment: The question asked, among other things, for documentation, and the expression “an international keyboard layout” doesn’t really answer that. Which layout is this? It’s not US International.

Comment: Well, the OP can perfectly check out his system settings to know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can use `Ctrl+V <code>`.

- Example with the tilde: `Ctrl+V+126`
- Example with backtick: `Ctrl+V+096`

It worked for me!